# Enviar valor selecionado a um aquivo insert.php

Tags: ajax, dropdown, sql-insert

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber se há uma maneira de realizar um insert no banco de dados a partir de uma seleção em um DropDown.

Essa seleção seria enviada a um arquivo (exemplo) "insert.php", no qual realizaria o insert na tabela, e isso seria realizado com Ajax.

Tentei procurar algumas alternativas, porém, só encontrei métodos utilizando  com submit, e assim executando functions com o comando de Insert.

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: já tentou usar o <select> ? enviar o formulario com ajax e pegar o valor via $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

Olá
Precisa que no arquivo que contem o formulário
realizar uma chamada a um js que pode criar para receber os dados do formulário e seri-alizar.

```
    <src="script.js"></script>


<form id="Form" action="" method="GET" class="form-horizontal">
 ... campos do formulário
</form>
```

Arquivo js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#Form').submit(function(){
    carregando(1);
    // seria liza os dados do formulário            
    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
    //var dados = new FormData(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "arquivo.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function(data) {
            carregando(0);
             //msg = JSON.parse(data);
             //alert (msg);
             $('#ret').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

E no arquivo PHP recebe as informações por get e trata a inserção